# How to add multiple CSS attributes to a tag simultaneously?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to modify my WordPress theme the way I want through the Additional CSS part in *Appearance>Customize*.

I want all my `h1` tags in entry-content class to be like this:

[image: this image]

so I used this code:

```
.entry-content h1 {
  background-color: #cfbc00;

    display: inline;
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

I want the whole block to be colored `#cfbc00` and the background of the text itself to be black. But the browser does not apply these simultaneously to my tag and it applies only one of the attributes. What should I do?

Comment: Where is the html code?

Comment: @thebrownkid the html code is the text i'm writing as a wp post. its all dynamic

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the HTML code, then here is a CSS workaround:

```css
.entry-content
{
  position: relative;
}

.entry-content h1::before
{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #cfbc00;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.entry-content h1 {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #000000ad; /* Sets transparency according to sample image */
    top: 0;
    /* Line height to maintain the height of the :before element */
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
<h1>Test title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. the code nearly worked. But it has an issue that the line covers the text when i remove the z-index attribute. with the z-index attribute i have the same problem i asked earlier in my question

Comment: can you provide the screenshot of how it looked like or better provide a link to the site if on the server?